# How do you output API access information onto a logger file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a logger which outputs API access information onto a logger file.

I've created a log file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

application.yml:

```
logging:
file: restapi.log
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;
    //creating a new logger
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ProductsResponse getAllProducts() {
        //logging an event
        logger.info("abcdefg");
        List<Product> foundProducts;
        foundProducts = productRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I would like to output to a log file every time a specific method is ran in my controller.

Currently, I run the server and it runs on test mode and the server stops for some reason so I cant figure out how to send a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) to do this

Please take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) guide.

Comment: This also will be helpfull https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging